# Questioner or FAQ type radio to restrict new questions which are already answered

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

I might be asking a LOT but i think just like flagging system, we can have some radio buttons based screening before a New user asks a question. for example.

1. Are you looking for expiry of patent? if yes visit page how to calculate expiry.
2. Are you looking for contacting a patent holder? if yes visit how to contact applicant.
3. and so on.............

I request all of us to give a thought on this and improve our community.

Comment: Related Meta Stack Overflow post: [Thwart publishing duplicate and low quality questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions). I think that solution would be really nice for this, although there are some bits that would need working out.

Comment: Yes question is related to what i am asking. I will look forward since 70-80% questions are either duplicate or on hold i think we need to improve our ask question page to inform new user how and what to ask. Just help center link box is insufficient.

Comment: You may want to check out the [se-quality-project](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project?sort=votes) tag on [meta.se]. They're doing a lot of cool stuff in the interest of improving the quality of content on network sites, and you could definitely get involved in that. It'll be hard to get necessary momentum here, just because this meta community isn't very active. It's good for questions about [main], including feature requests that pertain only to the main site, but if something can be generalized, posting it there will lead to more community involvement.